# Spring update all entity with save

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, repository

Good morning everyone,
I am trying to update an entity completely through its id, I am using a repository that extends from JPA, I think that just by making it save the system it would crush the old one but it is not like that, I am getting this error:

```
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)
```

I have tried to use entityManager.flush (); but I get an error:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'flush' call
```

I have found options to update a database field but what I really want is to crush the database row completely, is it that complicated? How should I do it? Should I delete the record and recreate it? (I am not convinced because we are generating two transitions but I do not know if it is normal or not)

I put the code responsible for modifying the entity:

```
 @PostMapping ("/ user")
    public ResponseEntity postUser (@RequestBody User user) {
        Map <Object, Object> model = new HashMap <> ();
        entityManager.flush ();
        User newUSer = userRepository.saveAndFlush (user);
        model.put ("user", newUSer);
        return ok (model);
    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some test accounts I have found how to make it work correctly, I am doing something wrong, since when I make this code I get it correctly:

```
@PostMapping ("/ user")
    public ResponseEntity postUser (@RequestBody User user) {

        Map <Object, Object> model = new HashMap <> ();

        AtomicReference <ResponseEntity> responseEntity = new AtomicReference <> ();
        Optional <User> optionalUser = Optional.of (userRepository.findById (user.getId ()). Get ());

        OptionalConsumer.of (optionalUser) .ifPresent (u -> {
            u.setPassword (user.getPassword ());
            userRepository.save (u);
            model.put ("user", u);
            responseEntity.set (ok (model));
        }). ifNotPresent (() -> responseEntity.set (notFound (). build ()));

        return responseEntity.get ();
    }
```

So what I'm going to do is create a merge method in the User model to modify the data passed by parameter and save it correctly (I'm open to a better way, there may be more recommended ways to work, tell me please!)